# Contact structures transverse to a given line bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, contact-geometry

Let $M$ be an orientable $3$-dimensional manifold with a $1$-dimensional **continuous** distribution $F$ (i.e a $1$-dimensional subbundle of $TM$).

It is known that every orientable $3$-dimensional manifold admits a contact structure, and I have also seen here that contact structures have been classified in this case. My question is: can one construct a contact structure on $M$ s.t it is uniformly transverse to $F$ everywhere (equivalently the question could be stated as saying that given a continuous $2$-dimensional distribution $E$, can one construct a contact `perturbation` of it in the sense that it is as close as you wish to $E$ in $C^{0}$ topology). I believe that any continuous sub-bundle can be approximated by a smooth one, so the question is really: given a smooth plane distribution which is involutive (if it is non-involutive we are done), can it be approximated in $C^0$ topology by contact structures? It seems that Eliashberg and Thurston`s result is concerned with this question where they show that a foliation can be $C^0$-approximated by contact structures, but the foliation should not be $S^2 \times S^1$. I don't know how one would check whether an arbitrary perturbation of a given continuous plane field satisfies this condition or not.

Any references which might lead to better understanding of this problem are also very welcome (p.s: I am more knowledgeable on differential geometry then differential topology and or algebraic topology, so resources which are more geometric would be especially helpful). Any information about $S^2 \times S^1$-type foliations is also welcome.

P.S.: You can do this locally by choosing suitable coordinates and the distribution $<\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2} + x^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x^3}>$, but I don't know whether local considerations have any relevance.

Thanks